# join table code for three tables

Tags: java, jpa, entity, persistence

What would be the most elegant and maintainable way to write join table for 3 other tables?

Lets say I have three tables: School, Student, Teacher, all with primary keys (IDs).

Student can attend many schools, have many teachers.
Teachers can teach in many schools. Teacher can teach same student in different school (or not).

I seen many articles with Many-to-Many relationships between two tables, but cannot find a right way to deal with three tables,,

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly -in my opinion- you need to add something like the concept of `Course`. It is the relationship that tells you which `Student`s some `Teacher` teaches in some specific `School`.

I introduce it because I guess that not all `Teacher`s teaching in some `School` teach all `Student`s attending to that `School`.

- `Course` is kept on one `School`. `School` can have many `Course`s. (relationship)
- `Course` has many `Student`s. `Studend` attends to many `Course`s. (relationship)
- `Teacher` teach many `Course`s. `Course` has one teacher. (relationship)

In this set there is one `ManyToMany` relationship namely `Student`-`Course`. `Course` has `ManyToOne` relationships to `Teacher` & `School`.

Comment: That's a good idea to introduce new table. I will try adding intermediate table  as you are suggesting.

Comment: Yes actually it is the join table that joins the three tables. Just that the point of my answer is not introducing a new table (it was in your question already) but that that there is a need to think what is the concept behind the join. What relationship(s) the join table describes? Most propably it is something like `Course` which is also an `Entity` of its own.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with using an ORM to help you with these kinds of relationships. I think your relationship is many-to-many-through relationship.

Here's an article showing a possible match to what you want.

[Describing Relationships: Django's ManyToMany Through](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/describing-relationships-djangos-manytomany-through/)

Comment: Thx Richard, just found another article related more to Java JPA, https://vladmihalcea.com/2017/07/26/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/